# Ruby LinkedIn Scraper Gem retrieve specific fields

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I want to do a once of scrape for a college project. How do I adjust this code to only retrieve certain  fields such as first name, last name, title etc. The below  prints the full scrape of the entire page.

Linkedin Scraper Code is here [CODE](https://github.com/yatish27/linkedin-scraper)

```
require 'linkedin-scraper'
myfile = File.new("LinkedIn2.txt", "w+")
profile_names =[LinkedinProfile1, LinkedinProfile2]
profiles = profile_names.map do |profile|
    Linkedin::Profile.get_profile(profile)  
end
myfile.puts(profiles.to_s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to export them to CSV format use something like:

```
require 'linkedin-scraper'
require 'csv'

CSV.open('profiles.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
    profile_names =[LinkedinProfile1, LinkedinProfile2]
    profile_names.each do |profile_name|
        profile = Linkedin::Profile.get_profile(profile_name)
        csv << [profile.first_name, profile.last_name]
    end
end
```

Then you can open CSV file in Excel or Numbers to view or update.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted:

```
profile.first_name          # The first name of the contact

profile.last_name           # The last name of the contact

profile.name                # The full name of the profile

profile.title               # The job title

profile.summary             # The summary of the profile

profile.location            # The location of the contact

profile.country             # The country of the contact

profile.industry            # The domain for which the contact belongs

profile.picture             # The profile picture link of profile

profile.skills              # Array of skills of the profile

profile.organizations       # Array organizations of the profile

profile.education           # Array of hashes for education

profile.websites            # Array of websites

profile.groups              # Array of groups

profile.languages           # Array of languages

profile.certifications      # Array of certifications
```

your code will become:(for example)

```
require 'linkedin-scraper'
myfile = File.new("LinkedIn2.txt", "w+")
profile_names =[LinkedinProfile1, LinkedinProfile2]
profiles = profile_names.map do |profile|
Linkedin::Profile.get_profile(profile).title 
end
myfile.puts(profiles.to_s)
```